# Calculating albedo using NAIP imagery?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, imagery

I am attempting to calculate albedo using NAIP imagery 4 bands (visible-NIR).

[Zhao et al 2015](http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/7/9/12135) used quick bird imagery to calculate albedo using the following equation:

Albedo = -1.694(band1(blue))+2.749(band2(Green))+0.288(NIR).

Can I use these same coefficients that Zhao et al used?

Quickbird has band designations as:

```
Blue: 430 - 545 nm
Green: 466 - 620 nm
Red: 590 - 710 nm
Near-IR: 715 - 918 nm
```

and NAIP has band designations as:

```
Blue: 420-492 nm
Green 533-587 nm
Red 604-664 nm 
Nir: 833-920 nm
```

Comment: No, the dynamic ranges of the sensors are different. You would have to re-fit the regression(s) for the coefficients to be relevant for NAIP.

Comment: Thanks @JeffreyEvans.  Can you frame your answer as a solution, possibly with an example?

Comment: You have a tag for ArcGIS Desktop but make no mention of using that software.  How does it relate to the specific question that you are looking to have answered?